Matplotlib's plt.show() throwing "ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array"
I'm trying to run the following simple lines of Python code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([4, 5, 6])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

But 'm getting the following error for the plt.show() line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Pycharm/someproject/sam.py", line 36, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 612, in show
    return _get_backend_mod().show(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yz8zdw/Programs/pycharm-2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 41, in __call__
    manager.show(**kwargs)
  File "/home/yz8zdw/Programs/pycharm-2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 144, in show
    self.canvas.show()
  File "/home/yz8zdw/Programs/pycharm-2024.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 80, in show
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 387, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3161, in draw
    self.patch.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 632, in draw
    self._draw_paths_with_artist_properties(
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 617, in _draw_paths_with_artist_properties
    renderer.draw_path(gc, *draw_path_args)
  File "/home/user/Programs/miniconda/envs/plot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 131, in draw_path
    self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array

Environment information:
python                    3.8.20
numpy                     1.16.0
matplotlib                3.7.5

What's causing this issue?

You are using an old version of numpy. numpy 1.16.0 supports Python 2.7, 3.4 - 3.7 whilst matplotlib 3.7.5 supports Python 3.8 - 3.12.
One way to resolve your issue is to upgrade  numpy to a version that supports Python >=3.8. For example you can install numpy 1.24.4.
